# Defined variable in shiny app is not defined

Tags: r, shiny, scope

I am trying to use the variable `Z` in my shiny app, but it says the variable doesn't exist. I clearly defined it a few lines above the `lme` call. Does anyone know why the value of `Z` is not preserved?

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
library(nlme)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram

ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Use csv"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose csv file',
                accept = c(".csv")
      ),
      sliderInput("p",
                  "p:",
                  min = -2,
                  max = 3,
                  value = 1),
      sliderInput("q",
                  "q:",
                  min = -2,
                  max = 3,
                  value = 2),
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('sscPlot')
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output){
 
  output$sscPlot<-renderPlot({
    inFile <- input$file1
    
    if(is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    file.rename(inFile$datapath,
                paste(inFile$datapath, ".csv", sep=""))
    df=read.csv(paste(inFile$datapath, ".csv", sep=""), 1)
    
    visit=df$visit
    K=round(length(unique(visit))/4)
    knots=quantile(unique(visit), seq(0.05, 0.95, length=K))
    Z=outer(visit,knots,"-")
    Z=Z*(Z>0)

    model=lme(data=df, y ~ group + visit, random=list(group=pdIdent(~Z+-1), id=~1))
    
    plot(1:10)
  })
}



# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Error message: `Warning: Error in eval: object 'Z' not found`

Example data that you can turn into a csv file to try:

```
structure(list(id = c(101, 102, 102, 103, 103, 103, 104, 104, 
104, 104, 104, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 
107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 108, 108, 108, 108), visit = c(0, 0, 
4, 0, 28, 27, 0, 20, 19, 15, 6, 0, 12, 29, 27, 14, 0, 15, 1, 
26, 5, 0, 9, 28, 19, 3, 0, 19, 4, 6), y = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 
0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 
1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1), group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It stems from the [local vs global assignment](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/09/global-vs-local-assignment-operators-in-r-vs/) in R. Use   `Z<<-Z*(Z>0)` instead of  `Z=Z*(Z>0)` . But maybe there exists some other alternatives as well. This is the way I mostly use for solving the very same problem in shiny.

Comment: Not an expert about `lme` , but my guess is that `lme` tries to look for  `Z` in the data (where it cannot be found). So you should add your `pdIdent(Z+-1)` (whatever this does) as columns to `df` and  use the column names then in the random effect specification.

Comment: But, @maydin, `Z` is never referenced outside `renderPlot`. Could you elaborate how it could be a problem of scope?

Comment: Scope fixed it somehow!

Comment: @Jan You are right. I have no idea. But interestingly, I faced the same issue after running the codes above.  and `<<- ` solved it .

Comment: @maydin: Interesting. I added the scope-tag. Maybe we find someone who can explain it.